# Unexpected output when reading from getline into a non-empty string

Tags: c++, getline

I get confused with the "istream& getline (istream& is, string& str)"function, and according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/, the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream s("this is a test");
    std::string line = "line ";
    getline( s, line );
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    s.str("test again");
    getline( s, line );
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be:

**line this is a test**

**test again**

**test again**

but when I test it on Visual Studio, the output is :

**this is a test**

**test again**

**this is a test**

Could anyone explain the frustrating function for me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the error flags between the calls to `getline`:

```
int main()
{
    std::istringstream s("this is a test");
    std::string line = "line ";
    getline( s, line );
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    s.str("test again");
    s.clear()   // <<<--------------- to clear error flags
    getline( s, line );
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first `getline` sets `eofbit` on the stream. The second one then fails and `line` stays intact.

With the fix, you'll get:

```
this is a test
test again
test again
```

because `getline` doesn't add to the string, it replaces the content.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever value `line` has prior to the call will not matter, as from the [documentation for `std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> 1. Calls `str.erase()`

Your second logical error is due to reusing a stream once you've reached its end.